How to rephrase this question so that it adhere's to the site constraints
Thanks for taking time to read this question and providing constructive feedback.
I have read the help center information on how to ask relevant questions and I cannot think of a better way to ask this question. I feel that the answer is important as the question really focuses on building better relationships between people using language. Maybe I've been looking at this too long and I would like others to offer perspective on how to refine the question so that it meets the site guidelines and encourages reasonable answers.

It looks like the main reason the question got closed is that it is too broad and difficult to answer. On the other hand, you certainly did some research and put in some effort, so I'd like to help you find an answer.

Try asking the question in chat. There isn't much traffic, but it's worth a try.
Ask a new question about a specific scenario. Describe a situation where you want to build guanxi with someone, suggest some phrases that you have thought of, and ask for alternatives.


Thanks for the feedback. I have been having problems accessing chat but I will try again. Any suggestions on how to narrow the question so that I can re-open?

Describe a specific situation, @Tommie. It could be real or fictional, but describe two people's current connection and how one of them wants to change it.
